# How to make cart popup unique using ID so it wont affect other cart-popup?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have 3 cart popup, i have created 2 so far but the problem is they both appear before i clicked view-detail. I have tried to have each unique to the popup, but i am still not achieving this as my requirement. The requirement when i first click each of these they must popup on their own. Let me share my logic below.

// html code
`

```
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pb-1">
    <div class="card product-item border-0 mb-4">
        <div class="card-header product-img position-relative overflow-hidden bg-transparent border p-0">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/product-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body border-left border-right text-center p-0 pt-4 pb-3">
            <h6 class="text-truncate mb-3">Colorful Stylish Shirt</h6>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h6>R123.00</h6><h6 class="text-muted ml-2"><del>R123.00</del></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between bg-light border">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0 view-details-btn" id="cart-0"><i class="fas fa-eye text-primary mr-1"></i>View Detail</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0 add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-primary mr-1"></i>Add To Cart</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--View item details-->
    <div class="card-popup-container">
        <div class="card-popup" id="cart-popup-0">
            <button class="close-popup-btn">&times;</button>
            <div class="card-header product-img position-relative overflow-hidden bg-transparent border p-0">
                <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/product-1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body border-left border-right text-center p-0 pt-4 pb-3">
                <h6 class="text-truncate mb-3">Colorful Stylish Shirt</h6>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h6>R123.00</h6><h6 class="text-muted ml-2"><del>R123.00</del></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add-to-cart-btn">Add to Cart</a>
                <button class="close-popup-btn btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!---View details ends here-->
</div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pb-1">
                        <div class="card product-item border-0 mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header product-img position-relative overflow-hidden bg-transparent border p-0">
                                <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/product-2.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body border-left border-right text-center p-0 pt-4 pb-3">
                                <h6 class="text-truncate mb-3">Colorful Stylish Shirt</h6>
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <h6>R123.00</h6><h6 class="text-muted ml-2"><del>R123.00</del></h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between bg-light border">
                                <a href="" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0"><i class="fas fa-eye text-primary mr-1"></i>View Detail</a>
                                <a href="" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-primary mr-1"></i>Add To Cart</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <!----View details starts here--->

                <div class="card-popup-container">
        <div class="card-popup" id="popup-1">
            <button class="close-popup-btn">&times;</button>
            <div class="card-header product-img position-relative overflow-hidden bg-transparent border p-0">
                <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/product-2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body border-left border-right text-center p-0 pt-4 pb-3">
                <h6 class="text-truncate mb-3">Colorful Stylish Shirt</h6>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h6>R123.00</h6><h6 class="text-muted ml-2"><del>R123.00</del></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add-to-cart-btn">Add to Cart</a>
                <button class="close-popup-btn btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                <!--View details ends here-->`
```

// jquery

```
`$(document).ready(function() {
  // Set up click listener for view details button
  $('.view-details-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior of the link
    // Get the index of the clicked item
    var index = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    // Show the corresponding popup
    $('#cart-popup-' + index).show();
  });

  // Set up click listener for close button
  $('.close-popup-btn').on('click', function() {
    // Hide the popup
    $(this).closest('.card-popup-container').hide();
  });
});`
```

The above code is currently making them to appear before user click view-detail, which is wrong. The must first hide before any user view them as cart-popup. The code i use is not working as per my requirement and need some help based on the given code to improve my logic.

Comment: Are they set up to visibility:hidden or another css parameter? If you don't hide them by default they'll show up.

Comment: @OldPadawan no i did not do maybe that could also be my main problem, only did this on the front end side using bootstrap div id and jquery.

Comment: So you need to hide them by default and when user clicks, you set visibility of the targeted cart to visible by modifying the css property and it won't affect the others

Comment: @OldPadawan yes first hide and then when click show but not conflict with the second one

Comment: If you use unique id for each cart there should be no problem, because you would set visibility only for #1, 2 or 3 and not on .class applied to all of them

Comment: @OldPadawan do you min showing me an example to this so can continue making this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first hide your carts by adding a css property to

```
 display: none;
```

or

```
 visibility: hidden;
```

Then remove it on click on the parent button.

Here's a [working sample on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zf6hr4o/) or snippet.

Please note that I've modified your HTML for the carts as well as for the products, to make sure they're unique with unique ID and price/description so there's no conflict.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Set up click listener for view details button
  $('.view-details-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior of the link
    // Get the index of the clicked item
    var index = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]; //alert(index);
    // Show the corresponding popup
    //$('.card-popup-container').show();
    $('#cart-popup-' + index).show();
  });

  // Set up click listener for close button
  $('.close-popup-btn').on('click', function() {
    // Hide the popup
    $(this).closest('.card-popup-container').hide();
  });

}); // end document ready
```

```css
.card-popup-container, #cart-popup-1, #cart-popup-2 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!----View details starts here #0--->
    <div class="card-popup-container" id="cart-popup-0">
        <div class="card-popup">
            <button class="close-popup-btn">&times;</button>
            <div class="card-header product-img position-relative overflow-hidden bg-transparent border p-0">
                <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/product-2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body border-left border-right text-center p-0 pt-4 pb-3">
                <h6 class="text-truncate mb-3">Colorful Stylish Shirt 0</h6>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h6>R120.00</h6><h6 class="text-muted ml-2"><del>R120.00</del></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add-to-cart-btn">Add to Cart</a>
                <button class="close-popup-btn btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--View details ends here #0 -->
    
<!--View item details #1-->
    <div class="card-popup-container" id="cart-popup-1">
        <div class="card-popup">
            <button class="close-popup-btn">&times;</button>
            <div class="card-header product-img position-relative overflow-hidden bg-transparent border p-0">
                <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/product-1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body border-left border-right text-center p-0 pt-4 pb-3">
                <h6 class="text-truncate mb-3">Colorful Stylish Shirt 1</h6>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h6>R121.00</h6><h6 class="text-muted ml-2"><del>R121.00</del></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add-to-cart-btn">Add to Cart</a>
                <button class="close-popup-btn btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!---View details ends here #1-->

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pb-1">
    <div class="card product-item border-0 mb-4">
        <div class="card-header product-img position-relative overflow-hidden bg-transparent border p-0">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/product-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body border-left border-right text-center p-0 pt-4 pb-3">
            <h6 class="text-truncate mb-3">Colorful Stylish Shirt 0</h6>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h6>R120.00</h6><h6 class="text-muted ml-2"><del>R120.00</del></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between bg-light border">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0 view-details-btn" id="cart-0"><i class="fas fa-eye text-primary mr-1"></i>View Detail</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0 add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-primary mr-1"></i>Add To Cart</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pb-1">
    <div class="card product-item border-0 mb-4">
        <div class="card-header product-img position-relative overflow-hidden bg-transparent border p-0">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/product-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body border-left border-right text-center p-0 pt-4 pb-3">
            <h6 class="text-truncate mb-3">Colorful Stylish Shirt 1</h6>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h6>R121.00</h6><h6 class="text-muted ml-2"><del>R121.00</del></h6>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between bg-light border">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0 view-details-btn" id="cart-1"><i class="fas fa-eye text-primary mr-1"></i>View Detail</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-primary mr-1"></i>Add To Cart</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man saw i missing to add some css, make sense now, let me test it as i have seen the demo.